# What distinct sounds do guinea pigs make? and what onomatopoeias are commonly used to describe them?

Tags: guinea-pigs, vocalizations

I've been reluctant to ask this question as there many lists like this all over the net.  However, another [question I had about cavies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/how-can-i-un-train-a-guinea-pig-so-it-wont-wheet-when-it-hears-plastic-or-the?noredirect=1#comment4702_2133) made that there isn't a good list of all synonyms and what information is availalbe isn't presented as clearly as one would hope.  Therefore, I'm hoping this community can compile a comprehensive list of the onomatopoeias used.

### Most guinea pig noises are described by several different onomatopoeias, what triggers have they been associated with?

Answer (score 6):

## Guinea Pig Onomatopoeias and Their Meanings

### Weeak:

**Synonyms:** wheet. whistle, `squeek`, `squeel`

**Causes:** Excitement, anticipation; a call for attention, usually in association food associated sounds, requests for help

---

### Hesitant Week

**Synonyms:** Uncertain Beg

**Causes:**  Unclean cage, or a guess that food is near by

---

### Shriek (high pitched wheek)

**Synonyms:** scream, `squeel`

**Causes:** Pain, or great fear, or warning to stay away

---

### Bubble

**Synonyms:** `squeak` (shopping cart wheel)

**Causes:** Contentment, usually accompanied by occasional purring

---

### Purr

**Synonyms:** Sometimes confused with a rumble

**Causes:** Happyness, Joy

---

### Durr

**Synonyms:** Short Purr

**Causes:** Noises that frighten the guinea pig, annoyances

---

### Rumble

**Synonyms:** Deep Purr, Coo

**Causes:** Mating call

---

### Chut

**Synonyms:** Chubble, Mutter

**Causes:** Freedom, exploration, contentment

---

### Whine

**Synonyms:** Moan, Complaining

**Causes:** A pig is disturbed by another in it's own cage, or dislikes the way a human is touching it.

---

### Chirp

**Synonyms:** singing

**Causes:** Unknown; possibly because a guinea pig was startled, or just because

---

### Chuffing

**Synonyms:** (teeth) chatter

**Causes:** Angry, Upset guinea pig with the potential to become hostile

---

### Hissing

**Synonyms:** (none)

**Causes:** Anger, agitation; usually accompanies by teeth chattering.

---

References:

- [Jackie's Gunnie pigs]((http://www.jackiesguineapiggies.com/guineapigsounds.html) is a good reference that has recordings of many of the guinea pig noises.
- [Guinea Linx](http://www.guinealynx.info/behavior.html#chirping)
- [Guinea Pig Cornner](http://www.guineapigcorner.com/sounds-and-noises)
- [About.com](http://exoticpets.about.com/od/guineapigs/a/gpbehavior.htm)
- [Guinea Pig Manual](http://www.guineapigmanual.com/guinea-pig-sounds/) also has example noises
- [All about Guinea](http://aboutguinea.com/guinea-pig-sounds/)